# Pasar codigo de la vista al controlador Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estimados estoy teniendo problemas en mi servidor ya que la manera en que estoy haciendo las consultas me demanda muchos recursos y al subirlo a la web no me carga la pagina por ese motivo, lo vi en el log. Lo que hago en un .each sobre una tabla que contiene 'practicas' (medicas) y para cada una de ellas realizo un calculo de estadísticas que necesito (cantidad por mes, cant al mismo mes del año pasado, promedio, etc) y las muestro en un 'table'. La pregunta es si hay alguna manera en que pueda optimizar estas consultas ya sea pasándolas al controlador o alguna otra manera. A continuación les dejo lo que tengo hecho en mi view practices_index.html.erb

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 70%">Practice</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Actual</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Media</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">% Dif</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <% AuthorisationPractice.joins(:authorisation, :practice).where("authorisations.state in ('approved')").group('practices.code', 'practices.name').order('practices.name ASC').count.each do |practice| %>
    <% practice_mes_actual = AuthorisationPractice.joins(:authorisation, :practice).where("authorisations.state = ? AND practices.code = ? AND authorisations.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", 'approved',"#{practice[0][0]}", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month, Time.zone.now).length %>
    <% practice_1_year_ago = AuthorisationPractice.joins(:authorisation, :practice).where("authorisations.state = ? AND practices.code = ? AND authorisations.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", 'approved',"#{practice[0][0]}", 1.year.ago.beginning_of_month,1.year.ago.end_of_month).length %>
    <% practice_2_year_ago = AuthorisationPractice.joins(:authorisation, :practice).where("authorisations.state = ? AND practices.code = ? AND authorisations.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", 'approved',"#{practice[0][0]}", 2.year.ago.beginning_of_month,2.year.ago.end_of_month).length %>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><%= practice[0][0] %> - <%= practice[0][1] %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><%= practice_mes_actual %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><%= practice_media = number_to_currency((practice_mes_actual + practice_1_year_ago + practice_2_year_ago).to_f/3, unit: "") %></td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <% unless (practice_mes_actual.to_i == 0 or practice_media.to_i == 0) %>
                    <%= number_to_currency(100*(practice_mes_actual.to_i - practice_media.to_i)/(practice_media.to_i), unit: "%") %>
                <% end %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Lo que busco es generar una tabla de la siguiente manera, con todas las practicas con sus respectivas estadisticas, son aproximadamente 5000 registros.

[image]

La estructura de la tabla a la que accedo es la siguiente:

[image]

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de lo que tienes en la BD y la tabla resultado que buscas? Definitivamente puedes mejorar el performace, estás ejecutando demasiadas consultas a la BD; y sí, lo mejor es hacerlo en el controlador (o mejor aún, en un servicio).

Comment: @Gerry alli añadi la estructura de la tabla y lo que quiero generar

Comment: el inconveniente es como meter el '.each' en el controlador y poder imprimir los datos para cada practica en un 'table' en la vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso lo puedes lograr con una única query con contadores. En tu controlador agrega:

```
# Creo que Practice debe ser el modelo principal que consultes y no la tabla
# que relaciona con las autorizaciones. Creo que debería tener una mejora en
# rendimiento para tu consulta
@practices = Practice.grouped_with_counters
```

y en el modelo `Practice` (o lo adaptas a un servicio como sugiere Gerry):

```
# joins definidos en el método solo funcionarán si tienes definido:
has_many :authorisation_practices
has_many :authorisations, through: :authorisation_practices

def self.grouped_with_counters
  select(<<-SQL.squish
    practices.code, practices.name,
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN authorisations.created_at BETWEEN '#{Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month}' 
      AND '#{Time.zone.now}' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) AS COUNT_MES_ACTUAL,
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN authorisations.created_at BETWEEN '#{1.year.ago.beginning_of_month}' 
      AND '#{1.year.ago.end_of_month}' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) AS COUNT_1_YEAR_AGO,
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN authorisations.created_at BETWEEN '#{2.year.ago.beginning_of_month}' 
      AND '#{2.year.ago.end_of_month}' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) AS COUNT_2_YEAR_AGO
  SQL
  ).joins(:authorisations).where(authorisations: {state: :approved})
   .group(:code, :name).order(:name)
end
```

luego en tu vista, iteras las prácticas con:

```html
    <tbody>
      <% @practices.each do |practice| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= practice.full_name %></td>
          <td class="text-center"><%= practice.count_mes_actual %></td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <%= number_to_currency(practice.count_media, unit: "") %>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <% unless practice.count_zero? %>
              <%= number_to_currency(practice.count_diff, unit: "%") %>
            <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

y esa lógica de la vista, la hice pensando que en tu modelo de `Practice` (o en un helper, o un presenter si es que estás aplicando el patrón en tu proyecto) tienes definidos los siguientes métodos:

```
def full_name
  "#{code} - #{name}"
end

def count_media
  (count_mes_actual + count_1_year_ago + count2_year_ago) / 3.0
end

def count_zero?
  count_mes_actual == 0 || count_media == 0.0
end

def count_diff
  (100 * (count_mes_actual - count_media) / count_media).to_i
end
```

Comment: Intente este codigo y me arroja el siguiente error: 'Unsupported argument type: Time. Construct an Arel node instead'. En el .each de @practices

Comment: Estoy utilizando Rails 5.2.1 por las dudas

Comment: El problema es que rails no sabe como transformar las fechas en el `select` al formato de tu DB. Que mal, porque algo como eso no daría problemas en el `where`. ¿que engine estás usando?

Comment: Bien, estoy usando Postgresql

Comment: @francofernandez prueba el código actualizado del select

Comment: Genial, de esa manera me funciono. Le hice un cambio a la query y le saque la palabra 'SELECT' ya que sino quedaba duplicada cuando se ejecutaba la consulta. Ya lo actualice en la respuesta. Saludos y muchas gracias.